# Call to undefined method app\models\Message::model()

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am new with Yii2, using Gii tool,I have created the model and CRUD components for simple 'Message' class with one field 'content' mapped to tbl_message.

I am getting error, When trying to retrieve one message object by using findByPk function as follows:

```
$message = Message::model()->findByPk(4);
```

Error message:

```
Call to undefined method app\models\Message::model()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be enough :

```
 $message = Message::findOne(4)
```

More details and custom cases may be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data).